# Add class to clicked item, parent and grand parent and remove it from all the rest

Tags: jquery

**This is the html structure**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Stone age</a> > active
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Mesolithic</a> > active
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Culture</a> > active
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Neolithic</a> > not active > click > this active the others not active
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the third level, the first level looses the class active, when I click on the other element with no siblings or parent, it gets the class active but doesn't remove it from the previous clicked items.

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("a");
    $("a").not($parent).not($parent.nextAll()).removeClass("active");
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).nextAll("ul").toggleClass("closed opened");
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdsxnuwp/14/)

How do i toggle the class "active" between siblings, parents and other elements?

Comment: what elements actually have class="active" on them?  Your html example doesn't have that

Comment: ok i update the question but i did write when they have the class active if you double check next to the <a>

Comment: is the most outer `<ul>` wrapped by another element or has it got a class or id? just asking cause then it would be easy to remove `$(this).parent().parent().parent()`

Comment: i can add an id if I want yes, yet how do i toggle the class between siblings, parent and other elements?

Comment: @caramba check https://jsfiddle.net/fdsxnuwp/14/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
$("#myId a").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    // first remove all active classes
    $(this).closest('#myId').find('a.active').removeClass('active');

    // from the clicked item ($(this)) add "active" to all parents with children <a> 
    $(this).parents().children('li a').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="myId">
  <li>
    <a class="active">Stone age</a> > active
    <ul>
     <li>
       <a class="active">Mesolithic</a> > active
       <ul>
         <li>
           <a class="active">Culture</a> > active
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a>Neolithic</a>
       <ul>
     <li>
       <a>Mesolithic</a>
       <ul>
         <li>
           <a>Culture</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a>Neolithic</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @rob.m nice! Glad I could help, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

If you can add an id (or other method of uniquely identifying) to the top level UL element this becomes a fair amount easier. One way to do it would be as below:

```js
$(function() {
 $('#menu a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#menu a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active').parents('li').parents('li').children('a').addClass('active').end().parents('li').children('a').addClass('active');
 });
});
```

```css
.active {
 color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a>Stone age</a>
    <ul>
     <li>
       <a>Mesolithic</a>
       <ul>
         <li>
           <a>Culture</a>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a>Neolithic</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `$('#menu a').removeClass('active');` line will remove the active class from **all** A elements. The next line handles adding the class to the required elements, and there's a fair amount going on.

It starts with the element that was clicked on (`$(this)`), and adds the class to it. Next it finds the first parent LI (which is the level of the clicked elements), then goes up another LI level (for the parent of the clicked element). It then searches for any immediate children A elements in that element, and adds the class to it. Then it reverts back to the previous found element(s) (the LI) by calling `.end()`. Then it goes up one more level, again finds immediate children elements, and adds the class to it.

Comment: ok it makes sense, but I'd be honest with you, i was looking into a more generic solutions, because doing this will yes indeed answer my question with fixed levels of nested ul, yet if in any case we'd have a fourth level, then will need to change the whole js path to target the els. Yet it's good what you did, thanks